# raspberry pi gsm add on - serial port voice data

Tags: gsm, add-on

I have connected Raspberry Pi Gsm addon V.2 http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/RPI_SIM800_GSM/GPRS_ADD-ON_V2.0 with the Raspberry pi 2 through serial port. Ubuntu is running on the RaspberryPi. So far, I am able to originate calls from the GSM Module using AT Commands (using minicom).

However, once a gsm call is connected, the voice data is going to the on board Line In & Line Out ports only. How can i get the incoming voice data on serial port/ send outgoing voice data from serial port?

Comment: I dont think you want that. Have you considered the amount of data it will send?

Answer (score 0):

While looking to a similar I came across this question which provides an answer:

[Send wav sound through modem in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863141/send-wav-sound-through-modem-in-python)

However, according to the SIM800x datasheet, it seems the device does not support such use case..

Hope this helps, albeit a bit late !