# Send wav sound through modem in python

Tags: python, wav, modem

I am trying to make an automatic answering and calling machine in python and linux, but so far I was able to only call a number. 
When it comes to sending sounds or recording them I had no success.
I have been struggling with this problem for the past week and so far could not find a way to solve it.

The modem I am using is a Conexant Systems (Rockwell)

Here is the code I am using:

```
import serial
import wave
import time

def initializePhone():
    phone = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 112500, timeout=5)
    phone.write('AT'.encode())
    phone.write('AT+FCLASS=8')
    phone.write('AT+VSM=0,8000')
    return phone

def call(number):
    command = 'ATDT'+str(number)
    phone.write(command.encode())


def sendMusic(phone, music):
    cont = True
    while cont:
        frame = music.readframes(1024)
        if frame == '':
            cont = False
        ser.write(b"".join(frame))


def main():
    phone = initializePhone()
    music = wave.open('wood.wav','r')
    call('555555')
    time.sleep(10)
    sendMusic(phone, music)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can't send any voice without protocol ! [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link you sent me showed me the commands that the code was lacking

Answer (score 2):

Found the commands that were lacking on my script. Here is the new version with the fix.
I was missing the "AT+VTX" command before sending the audio data.

```
import serial
import wave
import time

def initializePhone():
    phone = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 112500, timeout=5)
    phone.write('AT\r\n'.encode())
    phone.write('AT+FCLASS=8\r\n'.encode())
    phone.write('AT+VSM=0,8000\r\n'.encode())
    return phone

def call(number):
    command = 'ATDT'+str(number)+'\r\n'
    phone.write(command.encode())


def sendMusic(phone, music):
    phone.write('AT+VTX\r\n'.encode())
    cont = True
    while cont:
        frame = music.readframes(1024)
        if frame == '':
            cont = False
        ser.write(b"".join(frame))


def main():
    phone = initializePhone()
    music = wave.open('wood.wav','r')
    call('555555')
    time.sleep(10)
    sendMusic(phone, music)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```