# How to make a sound call through a modem using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, gsm, modem

I've been looking for a solution to a software problem for a week now but we haven't found it anywhere

I have a normal Grameenphone modem now how to make a call with sound from this modem Using Python

I want to make sound through any file (mp3|wav|..). I want to use that sound in modem Using Python

**Please help me solve this question I have been looking for a solution to the problem for a long time**

Comment: This is a really good question, I guess the ISP or VoIP Configuration in your router along with its documentation might help.

Comment: Brother, what kind of question did I ask here and what kind of answer did you give? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863141/send-wav-sound-through-modem-in-python

Comment: So does this work?

Comment: make like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863141/send-wav-sound-through-modem-in-python